# How to access the Books API from a web application hosted on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: google-api, azure-web-app-service, google-api-dotnet-client, ip-geolocation, google-books

I have built a simple enough web application that uses the Google Books API to retrieve volume information for an ISBN the user provided. The application uses the official C# library. Requests are authorized by means of an API Key.

When running the app on my local machine I access the service with a German IP address and everything is fine. When accessing the Books API from Microsoft Azure however I get the following error:

> **Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError**
>   Cannot determine user location for geographically restricted operation. [403]
>   Errors [
>       Message[Cannot determine user location for geographically restricted operation.]
>       Location[ - ]
>       Reason[unknownLocation]
>       Domain[global]
>   ]

Does anyone know how to access the Google Books API from a web application hosted in Microsoft Azure?

Comment: WOW nice message there!   Where is the azure server hosted?   I want to test this.

Comment: @DaImTo The application is hosted in "West Europe".

Answer (score 1):

`country=us` URL param solved this for me, mentioned in [this github project](https://github.com/zeantsoi/GoogleBooks#geolocation), but not documented in the [volumes list](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes/list) route of course

[This blog](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/google-books-api-gotcha-internal-ip-address-503-cannot-determine-user-location/) says you can also use x-forwarded-for, I didn't try that

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have no idea if this will work.  But you can supply the ip address in your request.  This may or may not work if it doesn't let me know and I will delete this.

```
var bookService = new BooksService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
     ApiKey = "xxxx",
     ApplicationName = "BooksService Authentication Sample",
    });


var request = bookService.Bookshelves.List("user");
request.UserIp = "";  //<-- find an ip address to feed it
var result = request.Execute();
```

The thing is Google normally takes the IP address the request is coming from.   I wonder why it cant pick up a geo location from the IP address Azure is sending the request from.

Comment: Thanks - It's worth a try ;)

Comment: crossing my fingers.   If it doesn't work I know who to email at Google :)

Comment: Well - maybe it's not entirely google's fault: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mast/archive/2014/05/10/microsoft-azure-datacenter-s-ip-location-shows-incorrect-location-when-using-ip-geolocation-services.aspx

Comment: This approach does not work unfortunately. I set the IP address using `request.UserIp` and ran the application from the computer actually having this IP address successfully. However after deploying this to Azure the very same error occurred.

Comment: Going to email this to the dev on the client lib see if he has any ideas.

Comment: On a sidenote: I would be surprised if google would allow users to circumvent location-based access restrictions by simply spoofing the IP address - and even expose that spoofing feature as part of the client library... ;)

Comment: userIp is used for hacking around the quota to my knowlage.  I was hoping it would work for this as well.    Dev in question is in the USA will be a while before we hear from him.   I will keep you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101170/discussion-between-daimto-and-spontifixus).

Comment: Are there any news on this topic?